# How to find Next and Previous searched strings?

Tags: c#, string

So I am trying to make a GUI which find the users searched word in the richtextbox. I have two buttons, one to find the next location of the the string and highlight and the other button is to find the previous location of the searched string. My "Next" button works fine and highlights the next string location in the text each time you click it. But my previous button does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
int index = 0;

       //NEXT BUTTON
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        richTextBox1.Find(textBox2.Text, index, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
        index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox2.Text, index) + 1;
    }

           // PREVIOUS BUTTON
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        richTextBox1.Find(textBox2.Text, index -1, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox2.Text, index) - 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to calculate new index by yourself. Use result of Find method, it gives you correct index. If you want to search backwards use RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse. Accidentally you also didn't set color to yellow in previous button.

Edited code. It works now as it should.

```
    int selectionStart = 0;
    int selectionStop = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;

        selectionStart = richTextBox1.Find(textBox1.Text, selectionStop, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        selectionStop = selectionStart + textBox1.Text.Length;

        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;

        selectionStart = richTextBox1.Find(textBox1.Text, 0, selectionStart, RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse);
        selectionStop = selectionStart + textBox1.Text.Length;

        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer but I've finally worked out a solution to this problem. Hopefully helps someone else. This will find and select the next/previous word searched for based off the current caret position in the richtextbox. It is case insensitive and ignores hidden XAML characters i.e. if you search for formatted text it will actually find it.

Use the SelectWord() method below to pass in the text from your searchbox. Tie this method to your next/previous buttons like shown below. One useful trick I learned while developing this code was to use a TextRange to show the text between 2 text pointers 
e.g. string debugText = new TextRange(texpointer1, textpointer2).Text;

```
    private void PreviousButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectWord(SearchTextbox.Text, LogicalDirection.Backward);
    }

    private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectWord(SearchTextbox.Text, LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a string input and searches richtextbox in the direction specified.  
    /// </summary>
    private void SelectWord(string input, LogicalDirection direction)
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = ClRichTextBox; //the name of your richtextbox control

        TextPointer currentStartposition = rtb.Selection.Start;
        TextPointer currentEndposition = rtb.Selection.End;
        TextPointer position;
        TextPointer previousPosition;
        string textLine = null;
        if (direction == LogicalDirection.Forward)
        {
            position = currentStartposition.GetLineStartPosition(1);
            previousPosition = currentEndposition;
            if (position != null)
                textLine = new TextRange(previousPosition, position).Text;
        }
        else
        {
            position = currentStartposition.GetLineStartPosition(0);
            previousPosition = currentStartposition;
            if (position != null)
                textLine = new TextRange(position, previousPosition).Text;
        }

        while (position != null)
        {
            int indexInRun;
            if (direction == LogicalDirection.Forward)
                indexInRun = textLine.IndexOf(input, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            else
                indexInRun = textLine.LastIndexOf(input, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

            if (indexInRun >= 0)
            {
                TextPointer nextPointer = null;
                if (direction == LogicalDirection.Forward)
                    position = previousPosition;

                int inputLength = input.Length;
                while (nextPointer == null)
                {
                    if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text && nextPointer == null) //checks to see if textpointer is actually text
                    {
                        string textRun = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                        if (textRun.Length - 1 < indexInRun)
                            indexInRun -= textRun.Length;
                        else //found the start position of text pointer
                        {
                            position = position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
                            nextPointer = position;
                            while (inputLength > 0)
                            {
                                textRun = nextPointer.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                                if (textRun.Length - indexInRun < inputLength)
                                {
                                    inputLength -= textRun.Length;
                                    indexInRun = 0; //after the first pass, index in run is no longer relevant
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    nextPointer = nextPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(inputLength);
                                    rtb.Selection.Select(position, nextPointer);
                                    rtb.Focus();

                                    //moves the scrollbar to the selected text
                                    Rect r = position.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                                    double totaloffset = r.Top + rtb.VerticalOffset;
                                    rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(totaloffset - rtb.ActualHeight / 2);
                                    return; //word is selected and scrolled to. Exit method
                                }
                                nextPointer = nextPointer.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                }
            }

            previousPosition = position;
            if (direction == LogicalDirection.Forward)
            {
                position = position.GetLineStartPosition(1);
                if (position != null)
                    textLine = new TextRange(previousPosition, position).Text;
            }
            else
            {
                position = position.GetLineStartPosition(-1);
                if (position != null)
                    textLine = new TextRange(position, previousPosition).Text;
            }

        }

        //if next/previous word is not found, leave the current selected word selected
        rtb.Selection.Select(currentStartposition, currentEndposition);
        rtb.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: I tested this, works fine, but some times in stays in "while (nextPointer == null)" loop forever